# Hashed password conversion in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am converting oracle stored passwords to postgres. We stored password in oracle as follows.

```
ltrim( to_char( dbms_utility.get_hash_value( upper(name)||'/'||upper(password), 05736, power(2,20) ),rpad( 'X',43,'X')||'X' ) )
```

if i write name and password as '**jhon**' it returns hash value '**42B21**'.
I need alternative for the same kind of functionality in postgres. 
Appreciate your help!

Comment: postgreSQL has [an MD5() function](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-md5/).

Answer (score 0):

If `password_encryption` is `md5`, you can calculate the encoded password as

```
'md5' || md5(password || username)
```

With `scram-sha-256`, it is much more complicated.